# How to transfer app from one Spotify Developer account to another?

Tags: spotify

We have Spotify Developer account with application, that already used by our iOS app in Appstore. How can we transfer app from one Spotify Developer account to another without changing Spotify app id?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to contact them. This isn't really a code question, or one that I can answer simply by being a developer. Try [@SpotifyPlatform](https://twitter.com/SpotifyPlatform) on twitter, or search https://community.spotify.com/ for an answer.